# Slick codegen not giving any output

Tags: scala, sqlite, slick, slick-codegen

I am trying to use the current version of slick and slick-codegen (3.2.0) with a sqlite database. When I try listing the table, I get the names properly. However, when I try to generate classes corresponding to the tables, I do not get any output.

This works:

```
object TableCodeGenerator extends App
{
    val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:sqlite:/home/samik/db/mydb.db", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")
    val tables = Await.result(db.run(MTable.getTables), 1 second).toList
    tables.foreach(println)
}
```

I get the output below:

```
MTable(MQName(models),TABLE,null,None,None,None)
MTable(MQName(users),TABLE,null,None,None,None)
```

However, the following code, run directly in the same way, doesn't work:

```
object TableCodeGenerator extends App
{
    val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:sqlite:/home/samik/db/mydb.db", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")
    val dbio = SQLiteProfile.createModel(Some(MTable.getTables))
    val model = db.run(dbio)

    val codegenFuture: Future[SourceCodeGenerator] = model.map(model => new SourceCodeGenerator(model))

    codegenFuture.onSuccess
    {
        case codegen => codegen.writeToFile(
            "org.sqlite.JDBC",
            "/tmp",
            "my.package.dao",
            "Tables",
            "Tables.scala")
    }
}
```

Meaning, the code runs successfully, but I do not see any output file. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above was happening because the underlying code was silently throwing an exception. The reason for this exception was that I was using a "feature" of sqlite where if you don't mention the datatype in schema, sqlite assumes it to be text type. However that creates a problem for the slick code.

More [details here](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1718). The immediate solution was to fix the schema, but I think this has now been fixed in slick as well.